# How can we convert a string (2007-01) to date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

How can we convert a string (2007-01) to date in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either a regular expression or use the `String.split` function to get the date parts and correctly build a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date) object:

```
// RegExp approach:
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2] || 1); // months are 0-based
}

parseDate('2007-01');
// Mon Jan 01 2007 00:00:00

// String.split approach:
function parseDate(input, separator) {
  var parts = input.split(separator);
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2] || 1);
}

parseDate('2007-01', '-');
// Mon Jan 01 2007 00:00:00
```

The above functions can take complete dates (`yyyy-mm-dd`) or only month dates as you want (`yyyy-mm`), if the day date part is *not present*, the first day of the month is assigned.

Comment: How can we convert the date into Month, Year format
eg: January, 2007

Answer (score 1):

You could use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library to help with the conversions.

Answer (score 1):

```
x="2007-01".split("-")
new Date(parseInt(x[0]),parseInt(x[1])-1)
Mon Jan 01 2007 00:00:00 GMT+0000
```